# Groupby rows, join and selection between a NaN value and a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform this dataframe:

```
A   B   C   D
xx  nan 2   3
xx  1   nan 2
yy  4   nan nan
yy  nan 5   nan
yy  nan 4   6
zz  nan nan nan
zz  nan 8   nan
zz  nan 9   nan
zz  7   10  nan
```

into this final one (by grouping by 'A' column)

```
A   B   C   D
xx  1   2   3
yy  4   5   6
zz  7   8   nan
```

I tried to use groupby,fillna and apply but with no results so far.

I want the final dataframe to always show, wherever it is possible, a non-nan value and the first value for each unique 'A' column value.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()
```

Alternative is [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with custom function if in future will be resolve [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427):

```
def f(x):
    y = x.dropna()
    return np.nan if y.empty else y.iat[0]
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(f)

print (df)
    A    B    C    D
0  xx  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  yy  4.0  5.0  6.0
2  zz  7.0  8.0  NaN
```

Comment: thank you for this jezrael, it is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can using `bfill` +`drop_duplicates`(This will keep the original index :-))

```
df.groupby('A').bfill().drop_duplicates(['A'])
Out[597]: 
    A    B    C    D
0  xx  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  yy  4.0  5.0  6.0
5  zz  7.0  8.0  NaN
```